# setState being blocked by callback execution

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project and have made my own accordion component. On one page in the app, I need to render a list of accordions and the content of each one must be fetched from an API when the header is clicked open. Currently, I have a piece of state called open in my accordion and I allow the user of the component to pass in two callbacks: onClickOpen and onClickClose. THere is a handleClick function that sets the state and then calls the callback in the setState callback.

My issue is that, it seems like set state is never called because when I console log the value of this.state.open it is always false. I'm assuming there is something happening with the callback but I'm not sure what.

Accordion Component (called Section):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import shortid from 'shortid';

import {
  SectionContainer,
  ToggleButton,
  HeaderContainer,
  Heading,
  BodyContainer,
  Body,
  Icon,
  Button,
} from './sectionStyles';


class Section extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    titles: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    children: PropTypes.node,
    data: PropTypes.object,
    noExpand: PropTypes.bool,
    showSecondButton: PropTypes.bool,
    onSecondButtonClick: PropTypes.func,
    color: PropTypes.string,
    widths: PropTypes.array,
    fontSize: PropTypes.number,
    fontWeight: PropTypes.number,
    secondIconName: PropTypes.string,
    secondIconColor: PropTypes.string,
    onClickOpen: PropTypes.func,
    onClickClose: PropTypes.func,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    children: null,
    noExpand: false,
    showSecondButton: false,
    onSecondButtonClick: () => {},
    data: {},
    onClickOpen: () => {},
    onClickClose: () => {},
  };

  state = {
    open: false,
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    if (this.props.noExpand) return;

    if (this.state.open) {
      this.setState({ open: false }, () => {
        if (this.props.onClickClose) this.props.onClickClose();
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ open: true }, () => {
        if (this.props.onClickOpen) this.props.onClickOpen();
      });
    }
  }

  renderHeadings() {
    return this.props.titles.map((title, i) => {
      return (
        <Heading width={this.props.widths ? this.props.widths[i] : null} fontSize={this.props.fontSize} fontWeight={this.props.fontWeight} key={shortid.generate()}>
          {
            this.props.showSecondButton &&
            (
              <Button onClick={() => this.props.onSecondButtonClick(this.props.data)}>
                <Icon className="material-icons md-32" color={this.props.secondIconColor}>{this.props.secondIconName}</Icon>
              </Button>
            )
          }
          {title}
        </Heading>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SectionContainer>
        { !this.props.noExpand && <ToggleButton color={this.props.color} open={this.state.open} />}
        <HeaderContainer open={this.state.open} onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
          {this.renderHeadings()}
        </HeaderContainer>
        <BodyContainer open={this.state.open}>
          <Body>
            {this.props.children}
          </Body>
        </BodyContainer>
      </SectionContainer>
    );
  }
}

export default Section;
```

Styles for styled components:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

import { colors } from '../../../theme/vars';

import { themes as themeTypes } from '../../../types';

export const SectionContainer = styled.div(props => ({
  boxSizing: 'border-box',
  position: 'relative',
  width: '100%',
  borderBottom: `1px solid ${colors.SLATE_BLUE_20}`,
  borderLeft: props.open === true ? `1px solid ${colors.MOSS_GREEN_FOCUS_13}` : 'none',
  borderRight: props.open === true ? `1px solid ${colors.MOSS_GREEN_FOCUS_13}` : 'none',
}));

export const ToggleButton = styled.button`
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  text-indent: -9999%;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  &:before {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      height: 12px;
      width: 4px;
      border-radius: .3em;
      background: ${props => props.color || colors.MOSS_GREEN_100};
      transform-origin: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
      transform: ${props => props.open === true ? `translate(0%, -50%) rotate(-45deg)` : `translate(75%, -50%) rotate(45deg)` };
    }
  &:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      height: 12px;
      width: 4px;
      border-radius: .3em;
      background: ${props => props.color || colors.MOSS_GREEN_100};
      transform-origin: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
      transform: ${props => props.open === true ? `translate(0%, -50%) rotate(45deg)` : `translate(-75%, -50%) rotate(-45deg)`};
    }
`;

export const HeaderContainer = styled.div`
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding-left: 16px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color: ${colors.SLATE_BLUE_100};
  background: ${props => props.open === true ? colors.MOSS_GREEN_FOCUS_13 : colors.WHITE};
  border-bottom: 1px solid ${colors.SLATE_BLUE_20};
`;

export const Heading = styled.div(props => ({
  boxSizing: 'border-box',
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  justifyContent: 'space-between',
  verticalAlign: 'center',
  width: props.width || '25%',
  fontSize: `${props.fontSize || 14}px`,
  fontWeight: props.fontWeight || 400,
  lineHeight: '32px',
  color: colors.SLATE_BLUE_100,
}));


export const BodyContainer = styled.div(props => ({
  boxSizing: 'border-box',
  overflow: 'hidden',
  height: props.open === true ? 'auto' : '0px',  // how to transition this...
  transition: 'all .2s ease-in',
  borderLeft: props.open === true ? `1px solid ${colors.MOSS_GREEN_FOCUS_13}` : 'none',
  borderRight: props.open === true ? `1px solid ${colors.MOSS_GREEN_FOCUS_13}` : 'none',
  borderBottom: props.open === true ? `2px solid ${colors.MOSS_GREEN_100}` : 'none',
  background: colors.WHITE,
}));

export const Body = styled.div(props => ({
  boxSizing: 'border-box',
  padding: '1em',
  color: '#333',
  lineHeight: '1.3',
}));

export const Icon = styled.i`
  color: ${props => props.color};
  font-size: '32px';
  margin-top: auto;
`;

export const Button = styled.button`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-self: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
`;
```

I use the Section component like this:

```
class MEPlotAccordion extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    row: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    clearSelectedNode: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    fetchSelectedNode: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    selectedNode: PropTypes.object,
    isFetchingSelectedNode: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    selectedNode: {},
  };

  onClickOpen = (nodeId) => {
  // the callback that is called from the Section handleClick
    this.props.fetchSelectedNode({ type: nodeTypes.MODEL_ELEMENT, id: nodeId });
  };

  onClickClose = () => {
    this.props.clearSelectedNode();
  };

  renderMetaDataPage() {
    if (this.props.isFetchingSelectedNode) {
      return 'Loading...';
    }
    if (this.props.selectedNode) {
      // this component requires data from API to render
      return (
        <ModelElementMetaDataPage
          modelElement={this.props.selectedNode}
        />
      );
    }
    return null;
  }


  renderSeries() {
    return this.props.row.series.map((series) => {
      return (
        <Section
          key={series.id}
          titles={[`${series.name} - ${series.tagName}`]}
          onClickOpen={() => this.onClickOpen(series.id)}
          onClickClose={() => this.onClickClose()}
          fontSize={18}
          fontWeight={500}
        >
          {this.renderMetaDataPage()}
        </Section>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AccordionContainer>
        {this.renderSeries()}
      </AccordionContainer>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  state,
  selectedNode: selectors.selectedNode(state),
  isFetchingSelectedNode: selectors.isFetchingSelectedNode(state),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  clearSelectedNode: () => dispatch(actions.clearSelectedNode()),
  fetchSelectedNode: (nodeType, id) => dispatch(actions.fetchSelectedNode(nodeType, id)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MEPlotAccordion);
```

Comment: Where does `series.id` come from? Does the value of it always change every render?

Comment: it is a property on the series object. It does not change every render.

Comment: Have you checked if the `Section` component is being unmounted when you do the click action?

Comment: Hey you're right! It's unmounting! Why is it unmounting though?

Comment: My assumption would be you are providing a different key to Section every render. OR, the parent of Section itself is unmounting, therefore all the children of it is being unmounted as well. You would have to check that out. You can try checking if the parent is being unmounted or not. If it isn't, then check the key you are providing to Section component.

Comment: Hmm I can't see that happening but I can't rule it out either. I will test and come back to you. Thanks for the help so far! I really appreciate it!!

Comment: Ok you were right again... the parent of Section is unmounting but I don't understand why this would happen. The key stays the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196183/discussion-between-jackyef-and-cbutler).

Answer (score 1):

So, after discussion with the question author, the problem was that one of the parent component was unmounting on every render. The reason for the unmounting was because that the component was given a different key generated by `shortid.generate()` on every render.